# Accessing Spring Application Context in a External Library Constructed Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring Kafka library and I want to create interceptors with access to the ApplicationContext. However, this library creates the object for me and doesn't inject dependencies.

```
@Component
public class ExampleProducerInterceptor extends ProducerInterceptor<Object, Object> {
  @Autowired
  private Environment environment;
  ...
}
```

`application.yaml`:

```
spring:
  kafka:
    properties:
      "interceptor.classes": com.example.ExampleproducerInterceptor
```

Kafka itself uses this property to construct the object by calling the default constructor, outside of spring.

What are the methods of accessing the application like this? Can I, for example, provide a delegate class to Kafka to call the default constructor there?

I already have some code to configure kafka before it's constructed, so I can modify the class name before hand as well:

```
@Autowired
private List<ProducerInterceptor> producerInterceptors;

List<String> producerClassNames = producerInterceptors
  .map(Object::getClass)
  .map(Class::getName)
  .map(str -> str + "$enhancedBySpring") // Point to delegate class?
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your last code snippet is trying to achieve.

Depending on your application complexity, you can store the `ApplicationContext` in a static "holder" class or in a `ThreadLocal` and initialize the interceptor on the first call to `send()` or in the default CTOR.

```java
public class ContextHolder {

    private static final ApplicationContext context;

...

}
```

or

````
```java
public class ContextHolder {

    private final ThreadLocal<ApplicationContext> contexts = new ThreadLocal<>();

...
````

Comment: I want to avoid accessing the ApplicationContext through a static variable. For the last snippet, I want to give the Kafka library a delegate class that will inject my dependencies for me.

Comment: And what would that "delegate class" look like? Kafka knows nothing about Spring it will just instantiate the listener with its default CTOR - I don't see any way to do what you suggest.

Comment: The delegate class will have a default constructor and have access to the spring bean object. Then it will delegate all it's method calls to the actual spring bean. So when kafka library calls `delegateObject.onSend()` it will delegeate the method call to the Spring Bean object.

Comment: Basically, I want my class to look like a normal spring bean with the proper injection instead of manually accessing beans with a static `applicationContext` object.

Comment: `>and have access to the spring bean object.` - that's the bit I don't understand - how can a class have access to any object instance?

Comment: Spring creates proxy classes all the time, I'm wondering if I can do something similar manually.

Comment: `>Spring creates proxy classes all the time` - correct, but after creating the proxy, it instantiates it and **then** injects any beans it references. There's no magic here.

Comment: The delegate class will access the bean via static variable probably. I just want normal non static accessing beans on the front.

Comment: It's not clear what the proxy is for; you can simply do that in the listener's CTOR.